# Calculate percentage between 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to calculate % of completion between 2 dates (LeaseStart & Lease End).

Current % showing %Perentage column in the image is just a demo data.

on row number 4 it is displaying 100% as Lease End date was in April this year and I ran this today.

So whenever I run this report based on today's the system should calculate LeaseStart & LeaseEnd dates and show the %.

Please help

Thanks

[image: screen]

Comment: Dear Nadeem, this question was not tough (just bit lengthy). my suggestion is to try solving such simple questions yourself first. it will help a lot in your learning. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @table as TABLE(SR INT,LeaseStart DATE,LeaseEnd DATE)

INSERT INTO @table VALUES
(1,'2017-01-01','2021-12-31'),
(2,'2016-10-01','2017-12-31'),
(3,'2013-07-29','2018-06-30'),
(4,'2016-09-13','2017-04-07')


SELECT SR,LeaseStart,LeaseEnd,
DATEDIFF(DAY,LeaseStart,CASE WHEN GETDATE()<LeaseEnd THEN GETDATE() ELSE LeaseEnd END) DaysSoFar, 
DATEDIFF(DAY,LeaseStart,LeaseEnd) TotalLease,  
CAST((DATEDIFF(DAY,LeaseStart,CASE WHEN GETDATE()<LeaseEnd THEN GETDATE() ELSE LeaseEnd END)*1.00)/
(DATEDIFF(DAY,LeaseStart,LeaseEnd)*1.00)*100.00 AS DECIMAL(6,2)) AS Percentage
FROM @table
```

will RESULT

[image]

Comment: Plus 1 for the narrative

Comment: Hi Viking Thanks a lot for your help it working fine, Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I agree with your displayed results, but consider the following

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SRNo int,LeaseStart date,LeaseEnd date)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'2017-01-01','2021-12-31')
,(2,'2016-10-01','2017-12-31')
,(3,'2013-07-29','2018-03-30')
,(4,'2016-09-13','2017-04-07')
,(5,'2017-02-01','2019-01-31')

Select SRNo 
      ,Pct  = (DateDiff(DAY,LeaseStart,IIF(GetDate()>=LeaseEnd,LeaseEnd,GetDate()))*100.0)/DateDiff(DAY,LeaseStart,LeaseEnd)
From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SRNo    Pct
1       10.520547945205
2       62.280701754385
3       84.692082111436
4       100.000000000000
5       22.085048010973
```

Comment: Ah good. I must have refreshed page before doing and posting my answer :)